# How to get the selected UIElement(Image) in a Grid instantiated at Runtime?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight, xaml

My `Grid` has 2 rows and 2 columns (Total: 4 cells) created at design time. I added 4 `Image` controls to each cell (some Loop here: Row, Column Definition etc... Set `Grid.SetRow(imageControl, gridRowCell);
                        Grid.SetColumn(imageControl, gridColumnCell);`) at **runtime**.

Just for testing purposes, I would like to know if there is something I could use to return the specific selected `UIElement` in my case the `Image` when selected?

**Summary:**

- Each cell in the `Grid` has only 1 `Image` control instantiated at runtime.

**Purpose:**

My purpose here is to empty the Source of that child image when selected because soon I'll be replacing that empty image with a new one.

Please suggest me also in what `event` of `Grid` to place your suggested code. `Grid` doesn't have a `Click` or `SelectionChanged` event.

The **reason** I use Grid and dynamically add RowDefinition; ColumnDefinition because ListBox I think can't apply different item properties (i.e  displaying images with different sizes) within a bounded collection display but Grid can do RowSpan and ColumnSpan which can stretch to Rows or Columns spanned.

**e.g.** The user selects a layout format (4  cols & 3 rows; 5 cols & 3 rows etc...) which makes it harder to create at design time.

**In short:**

All I want is to display the Image collection items in different sizes and hopefully can still be done using Binding

[image]

Comment: See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.aspx) for documentation (and a list of events) on the `Grid` control. Note that [`MouseDown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.mousedown.aspx) and [`MouseLeftButtonDown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.mouseleftbuttondown.aspx) events exists, which might be of use here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want selection you should use a `ListBox`.

e.g.

1. Create a class for your images which has a property signature like this:

   ```
   Link : string
   X : int
   Y : int
   ```
2. Set up a `ListBox` with bindings and an `ItemsPanel` that is a `Grid`:

   ```
   <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ImageCollection}">
       <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
           <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
               <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="{Binding X}"/>
               <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="{Binding Y}"/>
           </Style>
       </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
       <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
           <ItemsPanelTemplate>
               <Grid>
                   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                       <ColumnDefinition/>
                       <ColumnDefinition/>
                   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                       <RowDefinition/>
                       <RowDefinition/>
                   </Grid.RowDefinitions>
               </Grid>
           </ItemsPanelTemplate>
       </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
       <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
               <Image Source="{Binding Link}"/>
           </DataTemplate>
       </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
   </ListBox>
   ```

You now can select the images and the `ListBox.SelectedItem` can be casted to your class and the `Link` can be changed.

You can also wrap the image in the `DataTemplate` in a `Button` if you want it clickable.

Comment: I just added "Reason" why I use Grid instead of ListBox. Hope my problem becomes clearer. Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: I updated my concern and added sample output using Grid (Applying RowSpan and ColumnSpan)

Comment: @user1078782: Can can still modify the grid (you can either replace the template or get the current instance using TreeHelpers for example) and you can bind the `ColumnSpan` and `RowSpan` in the same way you can bind the `Column` and `Row` (as shown above).

Answer (score 1):

There is no selection of items in a `Grid` so if you want to get the selected item there are three ways:

1. Replace the `Grid` by a `ListBox` and use the `SelectedItem`(s) property
2. Put the Images in clickable/selectable controls such as buttons so you can use the click event or monitor the IsChecked property.
3. Use the `MouseDown/Up` events of the `Image` control.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Selector`? `ItemsControl` does not have selection.

Comment: @Erno I updated my concern and added sample output using Grid (Applying RowSpan and ColumnSpan)

Comment: @user1078782 - In a way you changed the question, please don't do that because it will be harder for others to find this question and understand the answers. Even if you are worried about the layout (as you added) my answer remains the same. Option 1 is a little bit harder but still valid (see H.B.'s answer) Option 2 is very easy.

Comment: @Erno I didnt change the question. I just added more details about my concern

Comment: @user1078782 - and thereby you changed it from "How do I catch a selection?" to "How do I display this layout?".